# Recat Hooks how to detect a change if state is 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this effect:

```
React.useEffect(() => { 
   console.log('here'); 
}, [val === undefined ? null : val]);
```

But `val` can be `0`, so the effect is not being fired when `val = 0` since it thinks it is `false`... So how to tell React that fire the effect if `value` is `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effect will fire whenever one of the values in the dependency array changes.
Values inside of array are compared between renders with Object.is.

Comment: Your effect should fire at least once when your value becomes 0. If it stays the same between re-renders it won't fire the effect. 
I've created a little sandbox that shows 0 triggering useEffect: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-paper-9wt1k

Answer (score 4):

you can write the code this way it would work

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(val !== undefined){
    //do something
  }
}, [val])
```